# Clang fails to vectorize when comparing sequential array elements

Tags: c, loops, vector, clang, llvm

I am attempting to vectorize the inner loop of my alignment function, and have run into a problem I do not understand. When two elements that are sequential in the input array are compared, the loop does not vectorize, but when the elements being compared are offset by 2, it successfully vectorizes. A minimal example:

```
int *vec_test(int *input) {
  int i, n1, n2;
  int *out = (int *) malloc(100 * sizeof(int));

  // This loop fails to vectorize
  for(i=1;i<100;i++) {
    n1 = input[i-1];
    n2 = input[i];
    out[i] = n1 > n2 ? n1 : n2;
  }

  // This loop successfully vectorizes
  for(i=1;i<100;i++) {
    n1 = input[i-1];
    n2 = input[i+1];
    out[i] = n1 > n2 ? n1 : n2;
  }

  return(out);
}
```

When I use clang to compile this code (clang++ -O2 -Rpass=loop-vectorize -Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize -c minimal.cpp) the second loop vectorizes, but the first loop does not.

> minimal.cpp:17:17: remark: loop not vectorized: value that could not
>   be
>         identified as reduction is used outside the loop
>
> minimal.cpp:23:3: remark: vectorized loop (vectorization factor: 4,
>   unrolling
>         interleave factor: 1) [-Rpass=loop-vectorize]

The only difference is that the elements being compared are consecutive in the first loop, and offset by 2 in the second loop. Why does the first loop fail to vectorize?

**Edit:** Replacing the ints with different width types (int64_t, int32_t, or int16_t) yields the same results in all cases: the bottom loop vectorizes, the top loop fails to do so.

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that on 64 bit machines, the processor has to write out 64 bits at once, and you are using int which is a 32 bit type? Can you try changing int to int64_t (typically defined in <cstdint>) and see if it changes anything? Also, I know it's not related to your question, but your code is much more like C than C++. Highly recommend you use std::vector, or at least unique_ptr<int[]>.

Comment: Replacing all ints in the above code with int64_t, int32_t or int16_t yields the same behavior in all cases -- the bottom loop vectorizes, the top loop fails with the same remark.

Comment: And yes you're right that it is essentially C code. I updated the tag.

Comment: gcc 4.8.4 vectorizes both loops, doing unaligned loads with 4/8 bytes offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This failure looks like it was a bug in clang ~3.8 that has been addressed by 3.9.0.

```
$ clang++ -O2 -Rpass=loop-vectorize -Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize -c minimal.cpp
minimal.cpp:8:3: remark: the cost-model indicates that interleaving is not beneficial [-Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize]
  for(i=1;i<100;i++) {
  ^
minimal.cpp:8:3: remark: vectorized loop (vectorization width: 4, interleaved count: 1) [-Rpass=loop-vectorize]
minimal.cpp:15:3: remark: the cost-model indicates that interleaving is not beneficial [-Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize]
  for(i=1;i<100;i++) {
  ^
minimal.cpp:15:3: remark: vectorized loop (vectorization width: 4, interleaved count: 1) [-Rpass=loop-vectorize]

$ clang++ --version
clang version 3.9.0 (tags/RELEASE_390/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/clang-latest/bin
```

See also https://godbolt.org/g/Nw0kk1